# Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS

Tags: docker, virtualization, bios

I'm trying to run docker on windows 10 but I get this error: "Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enabled **Virtualization** from system BIOS.

DELL
Newer models: F2 key whilst Dell logo is on screen.
Alternatively: F1, Delete, F12, or F3.
Older models: CTRL+ALT+ENTER or Delete or Fn+ESC or Fn+F1.

Turn **ON** the System.
Press **F2** key at startup BIOS Setup.
Press    the right arrow key to **Advanced** tab, Select    **Virtualization**    and then press the **Enter** key.
Select **Enabled** and press the    **Enter** key.
Press the **F10** key and select **Yes** and press the **Enter** key to save changes and    **Reboot** into Windows.

HP
Most commonly: F10 or ESC.
Alternatively: F1, F2, F6, or F11
On HP Tablet PCs:  F10 or F12
Turn **ON** the System
Repeatedly press **Esc** key at startup.
Press the **F10** key for BIOS Setup.
Press the right arrow key to **System Configuration** tab, Select **Virtualization Technology** and then press the **Enter** key.
Select **Enabled** and press the **Enter** key.
Press the **F10** key and select **Yes** and press the **Enter** key to save changes and **Reboot**.

Reference Link: [https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968#:~:text=ON%20the%20System.-,Press%20F2%20key%20at%20startup%20BIOS%20Setup.,changes%20and%20Reboot%20into%20Windows](https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968#:%7E:text=ON%20the%20System.-,Press%20F2%20key%20at%20startup%20BIOS%20Setup.,changes%20and%20Reboot%20into%20Windows).